# The difference between Rig and Yajus chanting

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, vedic-chanting

There are primarily three Vedic (let’s call them) chanting styles viz. Rik, Yajus and Saman.

1. The Rik is defined as: when there is a division into ‘pada’ –
2. The Saman is defined as: when a mantra is set to music and sung.
3. The Yajus is the residuary one, defined as that which is neither Rik nor Sama.

Of these, as per the definition, being musical in nature, the Sama Veda chanting is very easily discernible : [example](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vGYqsA3p_zA).

I have a little difficulty in discerning the difference between the Rigveda and Yajurveda chanting styles. They seem almost same. [Example through comparison between both](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WskWGwVnTf8)

**Question:**
Could someone please explain the difference in the chanting styles of the Rigveda and Yajurveda with adequate examples and written explanation.

---

Note: This is not to try and learn chanting which is possible only from a guru. It’s just to see the difference between the two chanting styles.

Comment: Exploring on different meters used to chant verses, we may find answers from there.

Comment: A Mantra may be in verse, with fixed feet and syllables, when it is called Rc, or it may not have any fixity of feet and syllables, which is called Yajus. A Rc that can be sung is called a Saman. These three classes of Mantras have been grouped into four compilations or Samhitas, which are called the Rg veda, the Yajur veda, the Sama veda, and the Atharva veda samhita.